# Shortcuts for changing multilingual input source

Tags: macbook-pro, keyboard, shortcut, language

I'm using 5 languages, say E(English), and A B C D for the other 4 languages.
In windows, I'm able to use `ctrl+right shift` to switch to the next input(E→A→B→C→D→E) and use `ctrl+left shift` to go back(E←A←B←C←D←E). They are always in this order, so I know exactly what language I'm using.

Things are different on macOS, the order changes based on the last used language.
3 languages still work fine, because you can hit the key twice to get to the third input.
However, when there are >4 languages, I can't keep track of the rest (E→A→?→?→?).

Is there a way to get around this, in the sense that I can switch to the language without having to look at this [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know of any way to match Windows behavior, but you can set up a specific shortcut for each language with [Kawa](https://github.com/hatashiro/kawa), which may also help meet your needs.